# SQL count start xxx numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the records that start with 123, i need to count several times with different values, Starting with 123, 789, 567, ... I have those values ​​in the column2

```
 - column1 | column2
 - 1234567 | 123
 - 5489186 | 135
 - 1238756 | 548

SELECT column1, LEFT(column1,3) AS prefijo, column2 COUNT(LEFT(column1 = 123))
FROM DDBB.table
```

SOLUTION

```
SELECT LEFT(llamante,3) prefix, COUNT(*) quantity
FROM CDRcolas.`270`
GROUP BY LEFT(llamante,3)
```

Comment: Column1's data type?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(column1) FROM DDBB.table WHERE column1 LIKE '123%'`

Comment: column1 type varchar(50)

Answer (score 2):

Use `count()` function

```
select count(*) counts 
from table 
where column1 LIKE '123%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `Count`
FROM DDBB.`table` 
WHERE SUBSTR(column1,1,3)='123';
```